# How to fix: Relationships between two pivot tables

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, relationship

Im trying to make a relationship in laravel between 3 tables. First we have the "`decks`" table, which contains the information of every deck with `id` of the owner. Then we have the "`cards`" table, which only contains the information for the cards. Finally, I have two pivot tables, one named `CardsAndUsers` which contains an `id, card_id` and `user_id`, and another called `CardsInDecks` which only contains `cards_users_id` and `deck_id`.

The problem I have is that i dont know how to relation all of this.

I'm working with laravel 5.8

This is the structure of the tables

```
cards
  id
  title
  description
  cost
  type
  kingdom
  image
  health
  attack
decks
  id
  title
  description
  user_id
cards_and_users
  id
  card_id
  user_id
cards_in_decks
  card_and_user_id
  user_id
```

Deck migration

```php
        Schema::create('decks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('id', 255)->unique();
            $table->string('title', 255);
            $table->text('description');
            $table->string('user_id', 255);
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Card Migration

```php
        Schema::create('cards', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('title', 255);;
            $table->text('description');
            $table->unsignedInteger('cost');
            $table->string('type', 255);
            $table->string('kingdom', 255);
            $table->string('image', 255);
            $table->integer('health');
            $table->integer('attack');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Cards_and_users Migration

```php
        Schema::create('cards_and_users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('user_id', 255);
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('card_id');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('card_id')->references('id')->on('cards')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

cards_in_decks Migration

```php
        Schema::create('cards_in_decks', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('carduser_id');
            $table->string('deck_id', 255);
            $table->foreign('carduser_id')->references('id')->on('cards_and_users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('deck_id')->references('id')->on('decks')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Card.php

```php
{
  protected $fillable = [
    'title', 'description', 'cost', 'type', 'kingdom', 'image', 'health', 'attack'
  ];

  public function users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'cards_and_users')>withPivot('card_id', 'user_id')->withTimestamps();
  }

  public function decks(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Deck::class, 'cards_in_decks')->withPivot('carduser_id', 'deck_id')->withTimestamps();
  }
}
```

Deck.php

```php
class Deck extends Model
{

  protected $primaryKey = 'id';
  public $incrementing = false;
  protected $keyType = 'string';

  /**
   * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $casts = [
      'id' => 'string',
  ];

  protected $fillable = [
    'id', 'title', 'description', 'user_id',
  ];

  public function cards(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Card::class, 'cards_in_decks')->withPivot('carduser_id', 'deck_id')->withTimestamps();
  }

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
  }
}
```

I get an error saying that the column `cardindecks.card_id` doesnt exist (obviously). But i don't know why laravel expects it to exist.

**EDIT 1**

After researching I discovered i can pass more than one paremeter with the method `attach()` of a many-to-many relationship. I just had to pass `carduser_id` and modify my `cards_in_decks` table and add this field.

Example:

```php
$deck = Deck::find("5d09525cad67b");
$deck->cards()->attach(1, ['carduser_id' => 3]);
```

I feel very silly.